# No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts

Tags: postgresql, function, stored-procedures

I have created table in Postgres like as below.

```
CREATE TABLE rv_data_bkt_country_m
(
 interval_start timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
 creative_id integer NOT NULL,
 zone_id integer NOT NULL,
 country character(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::bpchar,
 city character(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''::bpchar,
 count integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
 CONSTRAINT rv_data_bkt_country_m_pkey PRIMARY KEY (interval_start, creative_id, zone_id, country, city)
)
```

When I insert using

```
SELECT bucket_update_rv_data_bkt_country_m('2018-03-14 08:00:00,1,1,'IN','',1)"
```

this query. It shows following error

```
ERROR:  function bucket_update_rv_data_bkt_country_m(unknown, integer, integer, unknown, unknown, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT bucket_update_rv_data_bkt_country_m('2018-03-14 08:00...
              ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the `create function` statement for `bucket_update_rv_data_bkt_country_m()` [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). [edit] your question do **not** post code in comments

Comment: Please post the code of your function. In case it is expecting a timestamp in the first parameter, try: `SELECT bucket_update_rv_data_bkt_country_m('2018-03-14 08:00:00'::timestamp,1,1,'IN','',1)"` Also, there was a `'` missing in your first parameter.